# SonarQube Configuration

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We had recently implemented SonarQube in our team and we have a dashboard configured

We've been able to see some of the details but the line coverage and code coverage is 0 always

Can you advise what we're missing ? I've checked the configuration and all of it seems to be in place

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the latest SonarQube version, note that, as mentioned [in this thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151)

> Version 5.12 of our SonarJava analyzer deprecated use JaCoCo’s binary format (.exec files) to import coverage.
>
> As a replacement, we developed the [sonar-jacoco](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JaCoCo+Plugin) plugin, which imports JaCoCo’s XML coverage report, and this is the preferred option now. I

That page illustrates how to include those reports for a maven or a gradle project. Again, it depends on the nature of your projects.